# RDiscount: Allow only certain tags

Tags: ruby, markdown, rdiscount

Is it possible to limit the set of allowed "tags" when using [RDiscount](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount)?
Let's say I want to prevent the user from creating lists e.g.? Or only allow bold and italic tags?

And if not, can this be done using e.g. [BlueCloth](https://github.com/ged/bluecloth) or some other parser?

**UPDATE**

I'm for now using [GFM](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) via [redcarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet) and after reading [How can I restrict Markdown syntax in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040504/how-can-i-restrict-markdown-syntax-in-ruby) I've added [Sanitize](http://wonko.com/post/sanitize) to strip out some of the tags Redcarpet generates. This solution works somewhat okay, but requires some nasty workarounds in cases.

In this sense — *I'm still very much looking for a better solution!*

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that there's no “baked–in” solution for this, so here's my work–around using [Redcarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet) and [Sanitize](http://wonko.com/post/sanitize):

```
markdown = Redcarpet.new(:smart, :filter_html, :hard_wrap)
sanitize_options = {
  :elements => %w(a strong em code pre br sub sup strike small)
}
html = Sanitize.clean(markdown.to_html, sanitize_options).html_safe
```